# How to show this weak formulation has unique solution?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Suppose $a$ is a bounded and coercive bilinear form on a Hilbert space $H$ and that $b$ is a bounded bilinear form on $H$ and $\ell$ is a bounded linear function also on $H$.

How do I show that: *For sufficiently small $\varepsilon > 0$, the equation 
$$a(u^\epsilon, v) + \varepsilon b(u^\varepsilon, v) = \ell(v),
\quad \mathit{ for\,\,all}\,\, v \in H,
$$ 
has a unique solution $u^\varepsilon$*.

I can't apply Lax-Milgram because $b$ is not necessarily coercive. What's the general technique for these kinds of problems?

Answer (score 2):

If $\epsilon$ is small enough, $a+\epsilon b$ will be coercive.

You can define $D(w,v):=a(w,v)+\epsilon b(w,v)$.  Since coercivity implies that the induced norm is bounded from below by an arbitrary vector up to the value of some constant $C\in(0,\infty)$, i.e. $$a(w,w)\geq C||w||_H$$  It is easy to show that $D$ is a bilinear form and that for small enough $\epsilon$ it must also be a coercive since if $b(w,v)$ is negative, you can reduce $\epsilon$ to arbitrarily small value ($b$ is bounded).